# Error while saving a matplolib plot to pdf

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, pdfpages

I am tryiny to save my matplotlib.pyplots to a pdf.  I am using PdfPages for it.

plot gets saved for :

```
pdf = PdfPages("Minion Plots - May 22.pdf")

fig = plt.figure()
plt.title('Counter')
plt.plot(data2['timestamp'],data2['counter'])
pdf.savefig(fig)
```

throws an error for

```
ax = plt.figure().gca()
plt.title('Time to Restart')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))
plt.ylabel('Time in Minutes')
fig = plt.plot(data1['Time to Restart'])
pdf.savefig(fig)
```

I am using

```
ax = plt.figure().gca()

for 

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))
```

error is

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Could you share the whole error please. Try to move `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))` to after `plt.plot()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
plt.title('Time to Restart')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))
plt.ylabel('Time in Minutes')
plt.plot(data1['Time to Restart'])
pdf.savefig(fig)
```

this solves the issue